# Assigning pair to a vector in C++

Tags: c++

Why do I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", when I do this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > hm;
hm[0] = pair<int,int> (1,1);
```

Comment: Out-of-bounds access -> Undefined behavior. Your vector is empty, you're trying to access the first element.

Comment: Try this same code, but simplify it – use just an `int` instead of a `pair`. Do you get the same results? If so, the problem is unlikely to be related to the fact that `pair`s are involved :)

Comment: To add to Andy's comment, use `push_back` or `emplace_back` not subscript operator.

Comment: What should I do? How can I assign some values to it? I can't just use hm.assign(n,0); because 0 ist an int and not a pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial size of this vector is 0 and `operator[]` doesn't check for bounds. You need to use the `push_back` method (which will automatically increase the size of the vector by 1 for you, and by size i mean the number of elements) or give the vector an initial size either with one of the constructor overloads like so:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> hm(5);
```

or with the `resize` method.

Answer (score 6):

The vector doesn't contain an element with zero index, it's just empty. You should add a new item:

```
hm.push_back(pair<int,int>(1,1));
```

Comment: And use `std::make_pair()`, possibly

Comment: Alternatively: `hm.emplace_back(1, 1);`

Comment: yeah but what if i want to add to a certain possition?

Comment: @randomguy, You'd find `insert` pretty quickly in any reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > hm;
```

you are creating an *empty* vector, that it, it contains no elements. In the next line,

```
hm[0] = std::pair<int,int> (1,1);
```

you are trying to assign to the first element of that vector without elements, which is undefined behaviour (and on your system *happens* to cause a segmentation fault, at least in the case you tried). If you want to catch such errors at runtime, you can use `at`, as in

```
hm.at(0) = std::pair<int,int> (1,1);
```

However the only thing you get this way is an exception instead of undefined behaviour, which doesn't solve the underlying problem, namely that you access an object that simply doesn't exist.

Now there are several ways to create that object:

First, you can create it "on demand" with `push_back`:

```
hm.push_back(std::pair<int,int> (1,1));
```

This causes the vector to append an object at the end (since the vector is initially empty, this is afterwards the only element, thus `hm[0]`, and initialize it with the value you've passed to `push_back`.

Another method is to give the vector elements from the start:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > hm(1);
hm[0] = std::pair<int,int> (1,1);
```

Here the argument at construction tells the vector to immediately create (and default-initialize) an element. Since there's now a first element, you can assign to it without problems. Note however that the default-initializaiton costs a bit of performance, and may not be available for some types.

In the specific case, you can also observe that all elements are equal (because there's only one), and therefore you can use the two-argument constructor here:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > hm(1, std::pair<int,int> (1,1));
```

In an unrelated note: Instead of `std::pair<int, int>` you can use `std::make_pair` and save yourself explicitly mentioning the type.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make `[]` behave like it does in Python and Ruby, then precede `hm[i] = j` with `if (hm.size() < i+1) { hm.resize(i+1); }`.